# property values returning undefined after instantiation

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, undefined, chai

This is a simple app to explore TDD with mocha. The app will be given two sets of poker hands and define the winning hand.

I'm having some issues figuring out why my value is returning undefined after I invoke a function on the object.  After instantiation, the individual variables store properly; but the variable which uses a function to retrieve those earlier values returns them as undefined. I am new to node/web development in general, and the only thing I could think of that it may be is sync/async?

The code can be found on github [here](https://github.com/GummyGuppy/tddpokerproject)

Here is the terminal:

```
images/undefined/undefined.img
{"suit":9,"val":1,"img":"images/undefined/undefined.img"}


  Test card module
    ✓ card is not null
    ✓ has all arguments valid and present
    ✓ has image value property
    1) has valid image path

  3 passing (13ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test card module has valid image path:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal 'images/s/1.img'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/cardTest.js:35:36)
```

and following is test file:

```
'use strict'

const app = require('express'),
      mocha = require('mocha'),
      chai = require('chai')

let expect = chai.expect

let card = require('../app/card.js')

describe('Test card module', () => {

  const myCard = new card.card('s', 1)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myCard))

  it('card is not null', () => {

    expect(myCard).is.not.null
  })

  it('has all arguments valid and present', () => {

    expect(myCard).has.property('suit')
    expect(myCard).has.property('val')
  })


  it('has image value property', () => {

    expect(myCard).has.property('getCardImage')
  })

  it('has valid image path', () => {

    expect(myCard.getCardImage).to.equal('images/s/1.img')
  })


})
```

and finally the app file:

```
'use strict'

function card(suit, val) {

  this.suit = suit
  this.val = val
  this.img = this.getCardImage()
}

card.prototype.getCardImage = () => {

  console.log('images/' + this.suit + '/' + this.val + '.img')
  let location = 'images/' + this.suit + '/' + this.val + '.img'

  return location
}

exports.card = card;
```

Any explanation would be highly appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function

```
expect(myCard.getCardImage()).to.equal('images/s/1.img')
```

And you should use plain function since you have dynamic context `this` in it

```
card.prototype.getCardImage = function() {

  console.log('images/' + this.suit + '/' + this.val + '.img')
  let location = 'images/' + this.suit + '/' + this.val + '.img'

  return location
}
```

Comment: Well the answer was a lot simpler than what I was expecting. I also looked into arrow functions and the problems they could pose with 'this'. So much to learn, thank you! https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/